# How to recursively append to an empty list?

Tags: python, recursion, computer-science

I'm new to recursion and finding it pretty difficult to grasp. I can't figure out how to append an empty array if I can't directly "touch" it. If its a string I would add the value each time. If it was a number that involved multiplication, I could multiply it each time, but with an array, I don't know what to do.

I dont know how to append to an empty array without being able to directly "touch" it.

This is what I've done so far:

```
def laugh(num):
  if num == 0:
    return []
  # This doesnt work since we can't append a function call. I'm unsure what to do.
  return laugh(num - 1).append("ha ")
```

## print(laugh(3)) -> ["ha, ha, ha"]

If could do this easily if i could just return a string of "Ha"'s instead. I could return an empty string and just add a "Ha" for each step.

Comment: `append` doesn't return a new object, it modifies the existing one. So `return laugh.append()` is just `None`

Comment: You could return `laugh(num - 1) + ["ha "]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify it like:

```
def laugh(num):
    if num == 0:
        return []
    haha = laugh(num-1)
    haha.append("ha")
    return haha
```

Since `append` does not return the modified list, you have to do it in two steps. Using concatenation and the ternary operator, you can shrink this to:

```
def laugh(num):
    return laugh(num-1) + ["ha"] if num else []
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you are mutating the list by calling append on it. What you want to do is return a **new** list:

```
def laugh(num):
  # base case
  if num == 0:
    return []
  # recursive case
  return ["ha"] + laugh(num-1)
```

Comment: Could you explain why I'm returning a new list? I'm a little confused? Since the base case will return [], which will become [] + ["ha"] on the next step.
EDIT - Oh, I guess with python you can add lists to another list to append?!

Comment: So it's different from appending one list to another because that is mutation. It is creating a new list that is the result of combining the two lists without any mutation. This is similar to (cons ... empty) in lisp or a lambda calculus based language.